# Gremlin query in Python to Neptune works if query not assigned to variable, else "Object of type builtin_function_or_method is not JSON serializable"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

I've connected to a Neptune DB in a Python3 Lambda function using these instructions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/lambda-functions-examples.html.

Currently, if I query it without assigning the query to a variable, like so:

```
g.addV('label_name').next()
```

I don't get any error and the node is successfully added to my Neptune DB. However, if I try to reference what's returned by the query so that I can give properties to the node I added, like this:

```
new_node = g.addV('label_name').next()
new_node.property('name', 'winston')
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Object of type builtin_function_or_method is not JSON serializable
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 85, in lambda_handler
        add_node(payload_dict)
      File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 175, in add_node
        <line where I assigned query result to variable>
```

I'm not sure why this is happening as I've seen plenty examples of people doing exactly what I'm doing and not having any problems. Any ideas on what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

You always need to use the graph traversal source (`g`) when working with a remote graph using the Gremlin Python client. The vertex returned from the query when using Python is just a local "reference" object that only has an ID and a label. You can do this all in one go, such as

```py
new_node = g.addV('label_name').property('name', 'winston').next()
```

or if you really want to do in using two calls, you would do something like

```py
new_node = g.addV('label_name').id().next()
g.V(new_node).property('name', 'winston').next()
```